# Looking for feedback on my approach to split data into validation and test set?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, validation

I want to perform a novelty detection using one-class svm (ocsvm) to detect network attacks. **I want to know how to split my dataset into validation and test set**. The dataset consists of five files. Each file is generated in a different day (five days) where each file has normal data instances and one type of attacks except the first file, which only has normal data instances.

Since I am doing a novelty detection, I will train my model on the first file data instances (which is only normal data). Concerning validation and test set, I am thinking to split the data in the rest of the files (four files) into validation and test set, meaning each file will have a validation set and test set. Then merge all the validation set files into one big file and do the same for the test set files then order them by date (date and time). Afterwards, convert all attack types instances into one label (1) and the normal data instance to (0) .

I want to mention that the instances of the network attacks differ from one file to another; for example, one file has only 11 attacks instances and about 700000 normal instances.

**Is this a good approach to split the dataset?? If yes, what percentage should I consider for the validation and testing sets?? Or is there any other better way to do it??**

Comment: Welcome to CV.SE! If each file has many data instances, then your dataset is five files multiplied by however many data instances there are in your files. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Another question: is there a reason stopping you from simply assembling all your data instances (ignoring the files) and training your SVM on this ensemble dataset?

Comment: @LmnICE Thank you. Yes, my dataset is five files multiplied by data instances; however, each file consists of different type of network attacks. Hence converting all the attacks class labels to 1. Concerning your second question I am not sure if I got it right. the idea is to train on normal instances (novelty detection) and validate and test on a instances with attacks. I hope that I was able to answer your questions

Comment: By "novelty detection" you mean you want to detect whether something is an attack of any kind? If so, I stand by my comment: if you train only on normal instances, then your SVM will be unable to recognize attacks in general.

Comment: @LmnICE Yes this is what I intend to do. As far as I know, OCSVM is suitable for novelty detection. Could you please explain why OCSVM won't be able to detect attacks?

Comment: My mistake, I thought you meant regular SVM in your question. Please ignore my third comment. In order to train ML classification models, you need correctly labeled data as an input. Are all your data points correctly labeled, or just the first file (where all data are in the normal class)?

Comment: @LmnICE it's alright. Yes, all the data points are correctly labelled in all files.